# Oracle expdp bash sh pass password with at

Tags: bash, oracle, expdp

According to:

https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g#expdp

passing authorization data we have pattern: [user]/[password]@[sid]

How to pass password with at (@) ? Such this is breaking a pattern and not work:

```
expdp scott/passw@rd@db10g tables=EMP,DEPT directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=EMP_DEPT.dmp logfile=expdpEMP_DEPT.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote like this:

```
expdp scott/\"passw@rd\"@db10g tables=EMP,DEPT directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=EMP_DEPT.dmp logfile=expdpEMP_DEPT.log
```

Answer (score -1):

You can always use quotes to isolate those problematic sections.

```
expdp scott/"passw@rd"@db10g tables=EMP,DEPT directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=EMP_DEPT.dmp logfile=expdpEMP_DEPT.log
```

That should work.

Comment: The quotes should probably go around the password, though? expdp scott/"passw@rd"@db10g